# A livewire component was not found

Tags: php, web, laravel-8

I try to run a web app in my localhost and end up encounter this problem. Previously the debugging is done using sftp and I'd never once run it on my localhost. Im new at this. Need guidance, thanks.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcEtn.png)

I'd try running the command given but still same error appear. How do i solve this?

Comment: Did you try to find the file `navbar.blade.php` inside folder `component/header` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the message that the header.navbar file cannot be found is displayed because the header.navbar file or component does not exist in localhost.

I think the first thing to do is check whether the header.navbar file or component exists in localhost. However, if the file exists in localhost, the header.navbar file or component pointed to by the framework may not be localhost, so it may be a good idea to check the pointing path.

Comment: I managed to solve this by changing

'class_namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Livewire', to     'class_namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers',